# Method 'replaceFirst' cannot be called on 'String?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error: Method 'replaceFirst' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
Try calling using ?. instead.)

```
.replaceFirst(r'$selectedRowCount', formatDecimal(selectedRowCount));
```

Comment: the variable you have used will be null so try adding a non null data to your variable then only you can implement operation in it.

Answer (score 2):

As Saffron-codes says, you cant do a replaceFirst on a 'String?' variable since it can be null, and dart is null safe.

There's two options for you to do. You can either make the variable a 'String' instead, if you do this you'll have to give it a value when initiating it:

`String variableName = ''`

Instead of:

`String? variableName`

You could also do a null-check (adding a questionmark before .replaceFirst) when calling replaceFirst, this is what it suggests doing in the error message 'Try calling using ?. instead.':

`variableName?.replaceFirst(r'$selectedRowCount', formatDecimal(selectedRowCount));`

Answer (score 1):

Add the `!` operator before `.` to make it non-nullable

```
!.replaceFirst(r'$selectedRowCount', formatDecimal(selectedRowCount));
```